# Canonical infinitely ambiguous languages

Tags: formal-languages, terminology

In an article I am currently reading the grammar

**S → SS | a | ε**

is being described as canonical infinitely ambiguous. The infinitely ambiguous part I have no problem recognizing, but does "canonical" mean? Does it mean "typical", "standard example" etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding the use of "canonical" here as "standard example" is correct; similarly, grammars for parenthesis matching or palindromes are canonical examples for context-free grammars, generally.